# Switching Color of a Progressbar programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

so i have a Layer-List with an Item with a shape and a solid color. Now i want to change this color inside my code.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <clip>
            <shape android:id="@+id/seekbar_shape_color">
                <solid android:color="#FFD00000" />
            </shape>
        </clip>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

i tryed getting the LayerDrawable and requesting the first item, now iam stuck getting the clipDrawable and finally get the ShapeDrawable

```
LayerDrawable sd = (LayerDrawable) v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_progress_bg);
((ClipDrawable) sd.getDrawable(0)).get..();
```

my other approach was to get the ShapeDrawable and setting the color with colorFilter but that doesnt work either.

```
ShapeDrawable sd = (ShapeDrawable) v.getResources().getDrawable(R.id.seekbar_shape_color);
sd.setColorFilter(R.color.cold_color,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

---

**edit:** ok so i developed a new plan
i tryed to use a LevelList like

```
 <level-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@color/hot_color">
    </item>
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@color/cold_color">
    </item>
</level-list>
```

i think the default value for Level is 0 but i dont get the progressbar displayed with the LevelList.
Also i dont know on which element i have to set the setLevel()

```
        holder.progressbar.getBackground().setLevel(0);
        holder.progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setLevel(0);
        holder.progressbar.getProgressDrawable().setLevel(0);
```

this calls give me strange results like only fresh progressbar items getting 100% progress coloration, smells like caching problem.

hope somebody can enlighten me how to use the LevelList properly on an LayerList for a Progressbar
thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this question is a few months old but I was able to get a level-list working with a progress bar.
The trick is to assign your levels values between 0 and 10,000
In my particular example I had 3 levels (red/yellow/green) used to represent battery life.

Here is how I did it:

**res/drawable/progress_horizontal_yellow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#ffffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#ffffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#ffffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**res/drawable/progress_horizontal_red.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#ffff0000"
                        android:centerColor="#ff990000"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#ffff0000"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**res/drawable/progress_horizontal_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#ff00ff00"
                        android:centerColor="#ff009900"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#ff00ff00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**res/drawable/battery_charge_fill.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="2999" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_red" />
    <item android:maxLevel="4999" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_yellow" />
    <item android:maxLevel="10000" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_green" />
</level-list>
```

Then in the layout file my progress bar declaration was like this:

```
<ProgressBar android:max="100" 
    android:progress="60"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BatteryLevelProgress"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/battery_charge_fill"   />
```

Then in java:

```
//progress is between 0 and 100 so set level of drawable to progress * 100
Drawable batteryProgressD = batteryProgressBar.getProgressDrawable();
batteryProgressD.setLevel(progress*100);
batteryProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
```