# Android custom Progress Bar manipulation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-progressbar

I'm facing some difficulties when working with custom ProgressBars in Android. Namely, I have two .xml descriptions of the custom ProgressBar that are correct.
Here they are:

1. custom_progress_bar_horizontal.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!--  @author : @ 

   -->
   <layer-list
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:id="@android:id/background">
       <shape>
           <corners
               android:radius="0dip" />
           <stroke
               android:width="1dp"
               android:color="#ff000000" />
           <gradient
               android:startColor="#ffEEEEEE"
               android:centerColor="#ffEEEEEE"
               android:centerY="0.50"
               android:endColor="#ffEEEEEE"
               android:angle="270" />
       </shape>
   </item>

   <item
       android:id="@android:id/progress">
       <clip>
           <shape>
               <corners
                   android:radius="0dip" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="1dip"
                   android:color="#ff000000" />
               <gradient
                   android:startColor="#ff86CF10"
                   android:endColor="#ff86CF10"
                   android:angle="90" />
           </shape>
       </clip>
   </item>
   ```
2. custom_progress_bar_hor_night.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!--  @author : @

   -->
   <layer-list
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:id="@android:id/background">
       <shape>
           <corners
               android:radius="0dip" />
           <stroke
               android:width="1dp"
               android:color="#ffffffff" />
           <gradient
               android:startColor="#ff000000"
               android:centerColor="#ff000000"
               android:centerY="0.50"
               android:endColor="#ff000000"
               android:angle="270" />
       </shape>
   </item>

   <item
       android:id="@android:id/progress">
       <clip>
           <shape>
               <corners
                   android:radius="0dip" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="1dip"
                   android:color="#ffffffff" />
               <gradient
                   android:startColor="#ff86CF10"
                   android:endColor="#ff86CF10"
                   android:angle="90" />
           </shape>
       </clip>
   </item>
   ```

As you can see, these custom ProgressBars differ only in the background color and the color of the shape line.

Now, what is the best way to toggle between these two .xml files (ProgressBar designs) from the Android app (java code)? Actually, I would like to toggle the ProgressBar design when the button on the app screen is pressed.

Should I have two ProgressBar instances one atop the other and change the visibility of them (one visible other invisible and vice-versa), or there is a smarter way to manipulate with a single ProgressBar instance?

EDIT:

I know for the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056285/switching-color-of-a-progressbar-programmatically). The user selects between three different .xml descriptions of the ProgressBar based on the current progress value using the following approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="2999" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_red" />
    <item android:maxLevel="4999" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_yellow" />
    <item android:maxLevel="10000" android:drawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal_green" />
</level-list>
```

I want to achieve the quite similar thing. The only difference is that I don't want the current progress value to change me the .xml file which will be visible on the screen. I want to be able to change the ProgressBar design by the press of a button. 
I feel that `android:maxLevel="xxxx"` selector should be changed with something which can take `true` or `false` values. I would toggle this `true/false` value by the press of a button.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Sincerely,
Bojan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call `setProgressDrawable()` on your `ProgressBar` in code and there is no need for two progress bars.

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_bar_horizontal));

progressBar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_bar_hor_night));
```

Comment: Right in the center, mate! This is exactly what I was looking for. You made my day and saved a lot of time for me. Thanks!